# Fill between y = 0 and positive values of y

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I'm practicing the fill_between matplotlib function.

What I want to do is to fill the area between y = 0 and the positive values of y and let the area between y = 0 and the negative values of y unfilled.

Something like:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = [1,2,3,4,5]
y = [0,2,-3,4,-5]

ypos = [i for i in y if i>0]

plt.plot(x,y)
plt.fill_between(x,0,ypos)
plt.show()
```

The error it gives is ValueError: Argument dimensions are incompatible. I've checked some possible solutions but I couldn't get it working.

Comment: It seems x, y1, and y2 must be of same dimension, which in your case are not. `ypos` is `[2,4]`, while `x` has 5 elements. I'm not sure if it's what you want, but you must fill the non-positive values of `y` with a number. Something like `ypos = [i if i > 0 else 0 for i in y]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use

```
where=np.array(y)>0
```

to restrict where the filled region will be drawn and use

```
interpolate=True
```

to have [`fill_between`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.fill_between) find the points of intersection:

---

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])
y = np.array([0,2,-3,4,-5])
plt.plot(x,y)
plt.fill_between(x, 0, y, where=y>0, interpolate=True)
plt.show()
```

yields

[image]